# How can I control multiple editing of wordpress posts?

Tags: posts, author, capabilities, wp-editor, multi-author

I am managing multiple authors blog, I have issues of editors taking over the stories that someone else is currently editing. The default wordpress warning will display but some of them ignore it and still proceed to takeover the story. I need a way of locking such stories to prevent editing unless unlocked by the user who locked them or a user of higher role/capability.[image]